# Structures in C declaration of a node for binary tree

Tags: c

```
struct node * newNode(int data)
```

Can anybody give me an insight what is `struct node*`?
what does `node*` is representing?

The intention behind asking this question is :

```
int main(void){
  struct node *node1,*node2;
  node1 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*node1));
  node2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*node2));
  node1->value=7;
  node1->left=node2;
  node1->right=NULL;
  node2->value=9;
  node2->left=NULL;
  node2->right=NULL;
  printf("%d",node1->left->value);
}
```

This is working fine ! now here why struct node* is casted? Doing struct *node is showing error.

Comment: no one can tell you what it is because `node` is not a standard C data type

Comment: Thanks! but I am confused with this declaration : \\
 struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); \\
Is node* is a pointer here?

Comment: You mean `struct node *node = malloc (sizeof *node);` and the fact that you can have a `struct node` and a pointer to `struct node` named `node` and the names not clash? Or the fact that `node` is just a pointer to the first address in the block of memory you just allocated with `malloc (sizeof *node)`? Look at it this way `struct node *somenode = malloc (sizeof *somenode);` and it will probably make more sense. (and is equivalent to using `malloc (sizeof (struct node));`)

Comment: The declaration `struct node *newnode;` creates a pointer to type `struct node` named `newnode` (don't use `camelCase` in C). Then `newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode)` allocates storage for 1 - `struct node`. You put it altogether (shorthand) with `struct node *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode);` (and don't forget to test `newnode != NULL` afterwards)

Comment: Thanks @ David C. Rankin
But could you please tell me the diference b/w node* and *node ,i know and read about the latter one but having hard time with former one.
what it represent in memory.

Comment: See comment below answer. Just keep straight that `type* pointer;` declares a *pointer-to-type*. If your type is `struct node`, the `struct node* pointer;` declares a *pointer-to-struct node*. (note: the `'*'` should go with the pointer and not the type, but this is for explanation) When you declare `struct node *ptr;` your create an uninitialized pointer of type `struct node`. You initialize it by assigning the address of memory that holds a `struct node` or allocate for one, e.g. `struct node *ptr = malloc (sizeof *ptr);` where `*ptr` dereferences a pointer-to-node giving `struct node`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! @ David C. Rankin,I got it .

Comment: Let's do it this way. `int a = 5;` (`a` hold the immediate value `5`), `int *b = &a;` (integer pointer `b` holds the address of `a` as it value). To get that value through  `b`, you dereference `b` (e.g. `*b` would give you the value `5`). If you just want to declare storage for another `int` via a pointer, `int *c = malloc (sizeof *c);` allocates storage for 1-`int` ans assigns the address of the new storage to `c`, then doing `*c = 6;` would store `6` at the address held by `c` see `:)`

Comment: @akhsay - you are welcome -- we have all been there, and sometimes you just have to beat your head into the wall enough times for it to sink in. Pointers are fundamental to C, so you just have to make friends with them. Slowly but surely. If you got this, you got 75% of it, you will just have to beat your head against the wall again to make friends with *function pointers* -- but that comes much later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are doing something related to binary tree. First Of all, instead of these 2 lines :-

```
  node1 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*node1));
  node2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*node2));
```

Use these (recommended):-

```
  node1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Also, the malloc returns a void pointer and it must be casted into the data type on the Left Hand Side.

```
node1= malloc( ...);
```

On the left hand side (above statement) the data type of node1 is `struct node` and so its pointer type will be `struct node *`. Therefore, `struct node*` is used as a cast as below.

```
node1=(struct node*)malloc( ... );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct NODE {
   char data[12];
   struct NODE* newNode;    //reference pointer
};
```

Here `NODE*` is just a reference structure pointer inside the structure, which can be used to hold the address of the variable declared inside the structure.

```
Don't get confused : *node :used as pointer 
          where as : node* :is used as reference

  struct NODE{
   char data[12];
   char *next;
};

typedef struct DATA Sample;

Sample *hptr = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks! but what is the difference between *node and node*(the one you mentioned).And what they do in memory.
(Newbie in pointers)

Comment: `*node` dereferences the thing (pointer) called `node`. A pointer is just a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. If you need to get the thing it points to, you *dereference* the pointer. `struct node* ptrname` is how you declare the pointer to begin with.  **Lightbulb - ON yet?**